# The editing reputation limit?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits, edits

The help center seems to suggest there is a limit on reputation earned from accepted suggested edits:

> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)

Do you simply stop gaining points from suggested edits once you have earned the +1000? What is the purpose of this? Doesn't SO want to continue to encourage users to edit and improve posts?

Comment: You're encouraged to edit posts (you even get the chance to edit every post without restrictions later), but past 500 edits, do you *really* need more reputation for doing this?

Comment: @Makoto: As for me, I don't _need_ more reputation for continuing to edit past the cap. I also see, after reading animuson's answer, that you shouldn't be able to get unlimited rep from editing posts. However, it would be _nice to have_, for example, +1 rep for edits 501 to 1000 as reward for still improving the site.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes, you stop gaining reputation for suggested edits once you've accumulated 1,000 from them.

The point of reputation gain is not solely to encourage editing - that's actually kind of an afterthought. The point of providing reputation for approved suggested edits is to provide users an alternate method to gain some of the basic features needed to use the site without having to ask or answer questions. It lets you get your foot in the door while you're still learning.

That being said, you're limited to 1,000 because at that point a user who has earned reputation from nothing but editing has gained all the basic features they need and it no longer makes sense to continue gaining reputation from editing. Past that, you start gaining more important privileges that we *don't* want users who have never even asked or answered a question to have. Privileges higher than that level require a wider range of participation and understanding of our site that you just can't get from editing alone.