# Why don't you continue to gain 2 rep for edits once you've reached 2k rep?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, reputation

I noticed that once I've passed 2k rep points, I don't get 2 points for edits anymore.

What is the rationale/reason behind this action?

I'm aware of the "Edit Questions and Answers" privilege. I'm asking whether the rep gain is more of a compensation mechanism.

While editing a post requires effort from the editor similar (more or less) to answering one, there is no compensation to the editing activity.

As of [Anthony Grist's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268480/11573842) - after 2K reputation, the gain might be less than +2 points per editing - it can be +2 points per 5 edits (or any other factor), but without some compensation to the editor on their time spent, editing will become less frequent.

Comment: [Privileges > Edit Questions And Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: You do get it for (accepted) tag wiki edits (until some other limit).

Answer (score 88):

At 2,000 rep, you gain the privilege to edit directly.

Before that, all edits are *suggested* edits, where the community will review them (in the suggested edits review queue). You gain +2 rep for the *approved* edits.

The idea being, you learn what makes good edits and get some reputation having made them.

By the time you have 2,000 rep, we see you as someone who understands what makes a good edit and not a learner anymore. The community doesn't need to approve your edits anymore.

---

Suggested edits are also a good way to help people who want to improve the site to gain some reputation, which may be difficult for them to achieve otherwise (asking good questions or giving good answers). Another reason to not continue after a while, is that higher privileges should be earned from participating in the site - not by just editing posts of other people.

Comment: This means the rationale behind this is to train new users on what is a good edit, right? isn't it to encourage them to actually edit (e.g., respect their time/effort with editing...)

Comment: @NirMH - can't it be both? Part of the reason is to also give users with low reputation a way to get some reputation (if they have problems with asking/answering well).

Comment: it is only up to 2K rep - after that, why would they edit? if nothing compensate for their effort spent? (see my post editing)

Comment: @Nir - after that? Perhaps to improve the site?

Comment: The rep system is hopefully not the _only_ reason you edit and improve SO - the idea is hopefully you want to improve it and help people.

Comment: @AlastairCampbell - personally i feel exactly as you say - i want to improve this site... but i believe many other people will stop editing feeling their efforts won't be appreciated (and the rep system is the major aspect of the appreciation - similar of answering). Don't you think?

Comment: @NirMH: When there is no incentive to edit, only those who _really care_ about the site edit.

Comment: @NirMH I've always looked at it this way: At 2k rep, your edits are not longer reviewed. You could edit a lot of spam in and get +2 for each instance if they didn't cut off that rep gain when you unlock the privilege. That is, up until you're caught and banned from editing.

Comment: @Kendra and others - why are you taking this topic to the dark side... lets assume user2 with +2K rep won't edit and put spam in - but they'll spend a lot of their time to contribute to the site, and get nothing except from self satisfaction. if as *Infinite Recrusion* said - altruism is the key message - people will contribute their time and skills just because they want to.

Comment: @NirMH The problem with that assumption: _This is the internet._ You reward someone for spam, they're gonna spam. Once I hit 2k, I'm likely to go through and edit what needs it, rewarded or not. If people don't want to edit without reward, they don't have to. No one's making them. This topic goes to the dark side because on the internet, there really isn't much of a light side.

Comment: @NirMH Don't forget that any reputation you get is the result of some other user, not only yourself: Either they upvote/accept your question/answer, or they award you a bounty, or they approve your edits. You don't earn any rep for things you do by your self (apart from the +2 you get for accepting an answer, but even then someone has to answer your question).

Comment: `i believe many other people will stop editing feeling their efforts won't be appreciated` We don't have to theorize about it, the policy has been in place for years and it's worked well.

Comment: I turned 2k recently and I came here as I searched for the same thing as the OP. Now however, I am more than convinced why I don't (and shouldn't) get those 2 points for each edit I make.

Comment: I just reached 2k now on SO and felt the same.

Answer (score 21):

I'd guess it's because at 2000 reputation you gain the ability to [edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit),  which means your edits are instantly applied and no longer require approval from other members of the site. It would be far too easy to then gain a lot of reputation very quickly just from editing if you still gained reputation from them.

Comment: Actually there is a cap on [reputation you can get from edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256024/the-editing-reputation-limit) So it's not like you can get "a lot" of reputation.

Comment: `far too easy to then gain a lot of reputation very quickly` is all about the correct answer. Simple right?