# Editing posts privileges

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation, privileges

I am now over 2000 reputation points on SO. When I edited a question, it was accepted automatically, but I didn't get the points and that was not explained. I was wondering what is the reason for not adding reputation points?

Comment: After 2k, you no longer collect rep for edits.

Comment: makes sense, probably just to stop people from collecting them through edits?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268481/998328

Comment: I'd close this question as duplicate if I could. Ta