# 2k rep not reached, but no +2 rep for edits

Tags: support, edits, reputation

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268479/why-dont-you-continue-to-gain-2-rep-for-edits-once-youve-reached-2k-rep) question and answers there say that there's no +2 rep after 2k rep. However, I'm not over 2k yet (1920 atm).

Why don't I get rep then? Is the limit really 2k?

My edits still need to be peer-reviewed and I don't yet have privileges to review others' edits.

Comment: You've made [550 edit suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2753501/zygd?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), which easily places you over the [1,000 rep maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) (*suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)*).

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's actually 544 edit suggestions.

Comment: @zixuan: it’s been 2.5 years since I made that comment; a number of posts have been deleted and you will not be shown the suggested edits for those, and new ones have been added after. Was there a specific reason you wanted to recount the number of suggested edits?

Comment: I just was checking if your comment was still true

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can only earn a maximum of 1000 reputation from suggested edits. You must have reached that cap.

Just earn 8 more upvotes and you'll be reviewing edits in no time!

Comment: Reputation audit page: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: True. The reputation audit page says: `earned 1000 reputation from suggested edits`.