# Wiki edits still gives +2 rep

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reputation, tag-wiki

A long time ago I stopped getting rep for editing posts.

But a few days ago I've edited a tag wiki and still got 2x`+2` (title and content I assume).

Should the editing of posts and wikis be handled differently when it comes to reputation?

I would have expected I get nothing for editing wikis...

---

Research:

> [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296985/2k-rep-not-reached-but-no-2-rep-for-edits) does say one can only get 1000 rep for editing posts.
>
> [And this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268479/why-dont-you-continue-to-gain-2-rep-for-edits-once-youve-reached-2k-rep?lq=1) At 2,000 rep, you gain the privilege to edit directly.
>   Before that, all edits are suggested edits, where the community will review them (in the suggested edits review queue). You gain +2 rep for the approved edits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11640538

Comment: @HansPassant, Yes, I know, but my question is: *should* we still get points? And will this stop once i get past the 5k rep (similar to post edit privilege)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Until you reach 20K reputation ([trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)), any tag wiki or wiki excerpt you edit is an edit suggestion.  It even enters the suggested edit queue and is reviewable by people with 5K+ reputation.

The only requirement for rep on suggested edits from [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) is

> suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)

So as long as you did not get 1K reputation from edit suggestions before you reached 2K reputation (full question and answer edit privilege) then you can keep gaining reputation from wiki edits until you reach the 1K reputation max or you hit 20K reputation and can no longer suggest any type of edit.

Comment: There's gold in them tag wiki hills, gold I tell you, gold!