# Is 2k reputations a good indicator to gain Editing Privilege?

Tags: discussion

This thread [Why don't you continue to gain 2 rep for edits once you've reached 2k rep?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268479/why-dont-you-continue-to-gain-2-rep-for-edits-once-youve-reached-2k-rep) explains everything about the 2k reps and editing privilege. The top answer says that

> By the time you have 2,000 rep, we see you as someone who understands
>   what makes a good edit and not a learner anymore

What about a user that has reached 2k reps but never or rarely edits a post? Gaining 2k reps from answer and questions doesn't mean that person is a good editor. Why don't use another assessment that related to post-editing, for example: you will need to get 100 edit approvals in order to gain the editing privilege?

Comment: If you need 100 edit approvals to be able to review suggested edits... how does anyone get the privilege in the first place?

Comment: Honestly, when I got my 2k rep I was not at all comfortable with doing direct edits. I was still unsure if they'd be correct or not. Same with many other privileges, actually - you get to a certain threshold and you're implicitly trusted to use tools you are not necessarily familiar with from prior use. I'd have personally preferred if there was an additional requirement - to have some accepted edits or to have some edit reviews under your belt.

Comment: @yivi I'm talking about the new regulation, people who have edited for more than the threshold will be able to gain it, we don't have to start everything from the beginning

Comment: Do you currently see a lot of bad edits by people with 2k but less than 100 approved edits?

Comment: @BDL it's a stat we can't easily see, if we can at all. But it might be worth exploring that somehow.

Comment: @BDL I do. I see lots of edits to put language names in code formatting, for instance, or putting JSON dumps into Stack Snippets.

Comment: @HereticMonkey your favorite tag is Javascript though... that tag suffers from it's own massive popularity.

Comment: @Gimby No need to rub it in, sheesh ;) I hear you, but just saying that 2000 rep isn't always a great measurement.

Comment: @BDL From my experience I don't see so many bad edits from people with 2k rep but I do see a lot of 2k+ rep users making completely pointless changes which would be shot down - I've seen some users add a single full stop or a single comma for what looks like a +2 grab.

Comment: @Matthew 2k rep users do not gain reputation for making edits. So these improvements are done only because the editors are helping both the post author and the site.

Comment: @yivi I was unaware of them not getting any rep, which leads to more confusion as to why some of the changes I've seen have been made.

Comment: Simple enough, @Matthew. To improve the posts, not to gain internet points.

Answer (score 10):

> Why don't use another assessment that related to post-editing, for example: you will need to get 100 edit approvals in order to gain the editing privilege?

This is a solution in search of a problem: as far as I can see, we don't currently have a big problem with new editors making lots of bad edits. According to the stats on the reputation leagues page, we have (as of this writing) 107,457 users with reputation >= 2000 in Stack Overflow alone, but SO Meta isn't overrun with complaints about improper edits.

I think that the current level of 2000 reputation points for editor privilege works because it indicates a level of personal investment in the community: if you've stuck around long enough and asked/answered with enough thoughtfulness to gain 200 upvotes, you've probably developed an interest in helping the community.

Answer (score 5):

There are long-standing issues with robo reviewers approving suggested edits that should not be approved so just because a user has 100 approved suggested edits doesn't mean that they are able to make proper edits. And that also raises the issue of who approves the suggested edits since that is currently gained at 2k rep along with the edit privilege. In the end there has to be some point where a user unlocks the ability to edit and review edits and with the problems that are known around review queues I find it hard to believe that approved suggested edits should be the wayl

[The robo-approvers are killing my will to review edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits/170567)

[What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted)

Answer (score 1):

To earn 2000 reputation points, a user must have made some *good answers/questions* where they have made **well formatted posts** which resulted in up-votes and reputation.

Even if a user made an incorrect edit, the question bumps to the homepage and someone can correct the edit. If the same thing happens again and again, moderators might take action against it.

> Editing a post also bumps the question to the top of the homepage.
>   Please be mindful of this and make your edits count, so that the new
>   attention is brought to something substantial.

Comment: It's one thing to do *formatting* but an edit can change anything and everything, not just the formatting. There is a lot more to be mindful of when editing other people's posts. Not to mention that you can introduce formatting that is undesirable for any number of reasons, not even just because the editor was explicitly vandalising a post.

Comment: **"user must have made some good answers/questions"**, not necessarily, can also be done with a lot of bad/mediocre question. Especially since question upvotes reward 10 points, it is easier to get a net gain even with downvotes. **"where they have made well formatted posts"** this is not necessarily true. When someone screws up the formatting, then it is highly possible someone else fixes it for you. It is possible the OP will then learn from that edit, but that is not guaranteed.