# What happens to existing suggested edits when you roll past 2000 reputation?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I have some suggested edits, but I’m less than 100 from 2000 reputation.

What happens to my suggested edits that are already waiting for review if/when I cross the mark? Nothing and they still need to be approved? Something else?

**I'm aware you no longer gain reputation for edits after 2000.**

[Why don't you continue to gain 2 rep for edits once you've reached 2k rep?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268479/why-dont-you-continue-to-gain-2-rep-for-edits-once-youve-reached-2k-rep) doesn’t address my question.

Comment: I was aware of that when I asked this question. I didn’t see the answer to this in there. Also title is entirely unrelated.

Comment: I think the close voters couldn't tell that you're asking about what happens to your **existing** suggested edits sitting in the queue once you cross 2K rep, not about future edits.

Comment: I’m getting so many pop ups asking yes/no is it a duplicate of that other question. Seems odd that close as duplicate flags seeming are not reading the question. I searched a long time for the answer to this question over close to week. I certainly couldn’t find this answer before I asked. I can’t be alone? Well, I guess I technically can be the only human that had this question.

Comment: "I certainly couldn’t find this answer before I asked." - My question would be, why do you even entertain the thought that anything special could or should happen? An honest question. I see so many people on meta make it way too difficult for themselves by questioning literally everything instead of just rolling with what makes sense.

Comment: Why? Two reasons: **1:** The mere existence of meta affords one so much understanding of the how it all works.  For very curious people, like me, it’s pretty awesome. **2:** I’ve found not everyone shares the same “what makes sense”.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nothing happens.

The suggestions don't magically auto-approve themselves, they still work *exactly* the same as when you have less rep.

Comment: I can confirm this from personal experience when I hit 2k.

Comment: Turns out, so can I now.

Comment: You should never see your own suggested edit from <2000 in the suggested edit review queue?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to occur, but i also wouldn't be surprised if it did

Answer (score 15):

Nothing. Your outstanding suggested edits still need to be cleared and you still get +2 reputation points once each one is approved (even if you are over 2000 reps at the time it's cleared).

But any edit you make after you cross 2000 reputation points immediately edits the post without review.

<sup>Apparently, it's not the same when you go back to close questions that you flagged to close before you hit 3000 reputation. I flagged a bunch of questions to close for various reasons before I reached 3000 reputation (and a lot of them were still under review for a while). When I reached 3000 reputation, I went back and voted to close those questions and to my surprise, my flags became "helpful" and got cleared from "under review".</sup>

Comment: Users only earn +2 reputation from an approved edit until they have earned 2,000 reputation from that action (i.e. first 500 edits)

Comment: @SecurityHound Re _"until they have earned 2,000 reputation from that action"_: I think you meant "until they have earned **1000** rep from that action"? Also, I don't see how that contradicts this answer. One could reach 2k rep without surpassing the 500-suggestions threshold.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine well the answer states it unconditionally, and that is not accurate since there are criteria for it. But you're right, 500 * 2 = 1000 :)

Comment: The clearing of your own close flags is a minor issue. I doubt anyone is going to be chaining themselves below 3k just to flag, and then going back above it to approve. There's not real benefit to doing so, just a higher flag count.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine You are correct; you can continue to earn up to 1000 total/lifetime reputation from suggested edits of any kind (including tag wikis or tag wiki excerpts) even after your account is at or above 2000 reputation. It just becomes significantly less common to do so because after 2000 reputation you can no longer submit suggested edits for posts.

Comment: About the Close Vote issue you describe: I [wrote a Meta.SE question about that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332075/295232) a while ago.