# Why does it take so long for my suggested edits to get reviewed?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I suggest a lot of edits. About two months ago when I started, it seemed like my edits were approved instantaneously.

Now, it takes nearly a day for the same thing to happen. It is a little annoying.

Why am I seeing such a difference in the amount of time it takes for suggested edits to get approved? What does this process entail, anyway?

Comment: Oh yes I am not a "new contributor".

Comment: You are a "new contributor" to Meta. This is a different site, and it resets the indicator. Kind of confusing; [been discussed before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372906/new-contributor-should-reflect-main-sites-not-meta-sites).

Comment: Because there are not enough reviewers. Keep in mind that also the reviewers are here in their spare time.

Comment: it takes roughly between [200 and 250 minutes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1021345#graph) for an suggestededit to get approved or rejected.

Comment: Perhaps we should double or even triple the pay we get to review those edits ;)

Comment: How about a bounty to get your edit reviewed faster, @hov?

Comment: @CodyGray: How many pizzas can you buy with reputation points? How many beers?  Nah, I'm talking cold hard *cash*, again, double what the site is currently paying me now

Comment: Of course math always gets me since 2 * 0 == 0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How fast an edit gets reviewed depends on the size of the queue, how many people are reviewing, and whether your suggested edits get Skipped in the queue. As of me writing this answer, there are 73 suggested edits in the queue and 3,296 reviews were done today.

If it's taking longer to get your suggestions reviewed then there are fewer people reviewing, a high number of edits in the queue, or your edits are getting skipped. Your edits are short so it's unlikely that a lot of people are skipping them (I personally skip most tag only edits but I'm likely an outlier) so it's probably just that it's Monday (people are busy) and people are having fun with the time machine (which isn't visible in the review queue).

Comment: Why do you skip tag-only edits? Just curious.

Comment: @CodyGray It's usually not a tag I'm familiar with and/or question I understand well enough to be sure the tag changes are good ones. Some are doable anyway because the edit comment points out that the tag except clearly state the tag shouldn't be used for that type of question.

Comment: But if a tag is wrong , then they wont have viewers @BSMP

Comment: @Programmer Skipping isn't the same as rejection. It just means that I'm going to let some other reviewer make the decision. Here is [an example of a review I skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22426561). I don't know Python so I can't tell by looking at that question whether matplotlib is the correct tag. The question itself never mentions it and the edit comment doesn't help. Skipping let two other reviewers decide on the edit.

Comment: I tend to skip tag-only edits too. As for short edits that's not necessarily the same, some may not like trivial edits and tend to skip, or refuse when it's quite nonessential.

Answer (score 11):

I rejected [one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22633428) of your edits earlier, my reason to reject it is because you were making trivial edit yet not fixing word errors & typo, also that question is a low quality question, it's going to be closed, your edit is likely to bring unnecessary review tasks to other people.

Since I have the feeling your name is familiar (probably skipped some of your edits), I looked over your [reputation log](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11093202/programmer?tab=reputation) and your [suggestion edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11093202/programmer?tab=activity).

I think [contributing / gain reputation mainly through editing is okay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381353/5403468), but your editing log shows that you were mostly suggesting trivial edits, many of them nonessential. And you recently have sometimes made 2 or [3 edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55388783/revisions) to same question, I think this is not good. Please try to make complete edit at once.
You can improve your edit before it's been approved, but after that please think twice before you submit suggestion again.

Please try to be comprehensive and serious when you make edits again, this will save everyone's time, thanks.

Comment: Turns out speed is not a benefit. Thankfully we're not that efficient so the OP has to slow down a bit giving them time to reflect. Also kudos for going over their suggestededits and offer advice.

Comment: OK then sorry @tiw

Comment: @Programmer It's okay :)

Comment: I make like a billion edits that are useless. @Tiw

Comment: @Programmer Not useless, many are still improvements. And you will change, right? Then it's okay, don't worry about it :)

Comment: @Tiw Ok thenYa Cool