# Should the reputation gain of the edits of same person to same post reduced?

Tags: discussion, edits

It's about the situation when one person edit same post multiple times.

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382312/5403468) leads me to thinking, is it reasonable that same person editing same post again will receive same amount of reputation?

How about reducing the amount of reputation one will get when they editing same post?
Say, 1 rep for editing same post again, and after some amount of revisions, none?

The reason to propose this, is because I think current setting is encouraging some editors, though few, to split up the could-be once-and-for-all edits.
Also I think keep *helping* others to do their own job, is not good and should not be encouraged here.

Comment: Someone writes a question, I fix it, the OP updates the question and introduces new issues, why do I not get the same reward for fixing it this time? Are we to discourage this? If so why?

Comment: @RobertLongson It's the OP's responsibility to edit/format their post well, especially when they are *updating* the post, and after someone already edited their post showed them the proper way.  Also my suggestion here, is the consideration of trying to reduce some repetitive tiny/trivial edits. Maybe, just maybe, some *diligent* people are intentionally editing same post multiple times.

Comment: It's not my fault if the OP messed things up again, why do I as editor get "blamed" for that.

Comment: @RobertLongson You don't get blamed, you also get awarded, it's just not as much as before. Also actually when it's the second time or third time OP messed up, it's the time comments, downvotes and close votes should be used, I think. Not many people like to keep cleaning other's mess, I guess.

Comment: You did notice the quotation marks around the word blamed? That's the word people will use when they complain about this. If we don't have many people willing to keep cleaning up messes then we should ensure the few that are willing to do so keep doing it.

Answer (score 7):

I don't like your suggestion at all. If someone improves the post, they should get rewarded. Your reference here is just faulty, this person did [3 edits on a single post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55388783/revisions), which should have been done in one edit, if needed at all. Personally in review I might have accepted the first one, or rejected and edited it, seeing that there was a typo left and the only real edit was just adding some code markup. The others I would most likely skip if seen stand alone, or reject seeing that there is still a typo left in the question.

We have the review option "no improvement whatsoever" for cases like this, which can be used to reject these trivial edits.

If the edit was substantial, even a second time (because the OP did a lousy job improving their question) we should accept.

Comment: It's just my thinking though.  And I never said they shouldn't get rewarded, just lower the rewards of same person to same post editing. Since current settings let me think it's encouraging some people to do split-up editing. IMHO keep cleaning other's mess should not encouraged, it's not helpful to either side. Anyway, just a suggestion.