# Do users get reputation points for doing edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, gamification

Does a user get reputation points for editing a question?

I ask because I have recently had a question edited in such an inconsequential manner I was left wondering why anyone would bother (for what it's worth, the edit in question did not fit within [the list of best practice edit motivations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), particularly with respect to "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit").

My best guess was the editor was attempting to accrue points, but I wasn't even sure if that was possible.

Comment: Yes. +2 per approved edit up to 1000 total. [what's reputation](/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Only if the user suggesting is under 2K reputation points (or is suggesting a tag wiki/excerpt after this point until the privilege to unilaterally edit them too is earned).

Comment: Right. If you're referring to [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67962861/2) then no. That was made by a user with [full edit privileges](/help/privileges/edit) (as Oleg mentioned)  and such an edit did not earn that user any reputation. It _is_ also very much inline with our editing practices of [removing fluff](/q/260776/15497888)

Comment: see also: [The editing reputation limit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256024/839601)

Comment: That user ought to have also [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67962861/) at least six other problems: near *"into [sqlite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite)*", *"without intermediate file"*, *"on th start"*, *"There are lot of"*, *"so that the instead"*, and *"doesn't work) ..."*

Answer (score 8):

A user with less than 2k reputation can earn up to 1k rep from suggested edits. +2 for each approved edit.

Users with full edit privilege (2k+) do not earn reputation from making edits.*

Editing is one of the primary ways one can contribute to the site. It's right there with asking questions and answering. The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) encourages that:

> Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them.
>
> Use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning of a post.

All edits are welcome as long as they are improving the post.  For suggested edits, we only ask that they are significant and fix as many issues as possible. This is so we don't waste reviewers time. Everyone else is free to fix any issue no matter how small as long as it doesn't change the meaning of the post.

*Users with less than 20k can still earn +2 for each approved tag wiki.

Comment: I think the limit is 5,000, not 20,000. *[Ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di/160292#160292)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Trusted user privilege is 20k https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user What you are looking at is reviewing suggestions in the review

Comment: That is not my experience. I got +2 for accepted tag wiki edit until I reached 5,000 reputation points. Did they change it?

Comment: @PeterMortensen maybe you just edit a lot and earned the max +1000 by then? :) I can confirm suggested edits to tag wikis/excerpts earning +2 after the 5K threshold.

Comment: @PeterMortensen what was your rep on August, 14th, 2013?